# How to always display the file name in JFileChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have JFileChooser to save a file to the local computer with the following working code:

```
final JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
fileChooser.setSelectedFile(new File(fileName));
final int returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(GeneralMessageDetailPanel.this);
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
//... save the file
}
```

When the user clicks the attachment link, the dialogue comes up fine, the `fileName` is displayed in the file name textbox, for example `MyFile.txt`. When the user clicks an other existing file in the navigation menu, the file name textbox will be this new file, this is ok. If the user changes the filename manually in the textbox, that is ok. When the user doubleclicks a directory or uses other means of navigation to change the directory the file name textbox will display this directory's path. For example: `C:\Downloads\test`.

**I would like the textbox to always display my default `fileName` even when the user changes directory.** So for example after a directory change, it should display `C:\Downloads\test\MyFile.txt`.

Thanks for the help, Sziro

Comment: `setFileSelectionMode JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY`? This should mean the user cannot save a directory (`getSelectedFile`). But nevertheless navigate through subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setFileSelectionMode JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY
```

(Credit to Joop Eggen, I only answer myself to close this issue.)